# Meteor Iron Router WaitOn Subscription

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I am really struggling with waiting on a subscription to load for a specific route before returning the `data` to the template.  I can see on from the publish on the server that a document is found, but on the client there is no document.

If I do a find().count() on the publish, it shows 1 document found, which is correct, but when I do the count on the subscription, it shows 0 documents.

I have tried a number of different methods, like using subscriptions:function() instead of waitOn:function(), but nothing works.

Collections.js lib:

```
SinglePackage = new Mongo.Collection("SinglePackage");
SinglePackage.allow({
  insert: function(){
    return true;
  },
  update: function(){
    return true;
  },
  remove: function(){
    return true;
  }
});
```

Publications.js server:

```
Meteor.publish("SinglePackage", function(pack_id) {
 return Packages.find({shortId: pack_id});
});
```

Iron Router:

```
Router.route('/package/:id', {
  name: 'package.show',
  template: 'Package_page',
  layoutTemplate: 'Landing_layout',
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('SinglePackage', this.params.id);
  },
  data: function() {
    return SinglePackage.find();
  },
  action: function () {
    if (this.ready()) {
      this.render();
    } else {
      this.render('Loading');
    }
  }
});
```

Am I doing something very wrong, or is this just a complicated thing to achieve?  One would think that waitOn would make the rest of the function wait until the subscription is ready.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the `data` function is running before the subscription is ready. Even if the `data` function did run after the subscription was ready, it wouldn't be a reactive data source rendering the pub/sub here pointless. [Here's a great article on reactive data sources](http://richsilv.github.io/meteor/meteor-reactive-data-types/).

Referring to the example from the [Iron Router Docs](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#the-subscriptions-option) for subscriptions, you would do something like this:

```
Router.route('/package/:id', {
  subscriptions: function() {
    // returning a subscription handle or an array of subscription handles
    // adds them to the wait list.
    return Meteor.subscribe('SinglePackage', this.params.id);
  },

  action: function () {
    if (this.ready()) {
      this.render();
    } else {
      this.render('Loading');
    }
  }
});
```

Then in your template.js:

```
Template.Package_page.helpers({
  singlePackage() {
  // This is now a reactive data source and will automatically update whenever SinglePackage changes in Mongo.
    return Package.find().fetch();
  }
});
```

In your template.html you can now use `singlePackage`:

```
<template name="Package_page">
  {#with singlePackage} <!-- Use #each if you're singlePackage is an array -->
    ID: {_id}
  {/with}
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Jeremiah.  I have tried this, but alas it is still not working.  If I do a count at the template level, I still get back 0 results

Comment: At what point in the workflow are you doing the count? onCreated, onRendered, helper?

Comment: Helper.. is that the wrong place? It's really weird, I can see the document on the publish but not the subscription

Comment: I see that your collection is defined as `new Mongo.Collection("SinglePackage");` in your collection.js. and then you're publication.js has the query `Packages.find({shortId: pack_id});`. Is your collection named `SinglePackage` or `Packages` in your MongoDB.

Comment: So I have a collection called Packages with thousands of documents in it. I then want a way to call just 1 document at a time, hence what I have done above. Is this the wrong way to do it?

Comment: Ah I see the problem now. What you need for the defined collection is `new Mongo.Collection("Packages");`. I think that should get you up and running.

Comment: Yeah, not that either I dont think.  I have already defined the Packages collection in the lib folder as Packages = new Mongo.Collection("Packages");

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.  I managed to get it working by searching the Packages collection on the client after subscribing to the SiglePackage publication.  Your help got me on the right path